# Burninate the [crockford] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

To support burninating movement I suggest to eliminate the [crockford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crockford) tag.
First of all, I respect and appreciate Douglas Crockford.

But my points are:

- Since its creation in 2012 there are only 55 questions tagged with it
- Tag is used to mention either book or algorithm or pattern, that is quite broad
- Tag is redundant since questions are self-contained so people don't require to have prior knowledge about what is meant by [crockford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crockford) tag in each question
- No one can be an expert about Crockford

Comment: "No one can be an expert about Crockford" I bet [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/153542) could!

Comment: I suggest adding `[crockford-algorithm]` and `[crockford-pattern]` tags if those terms are in widespread use. I don't think we need a tag for the book, so those uses of the base tag can just be removed.

Comment: I heard Jon Skeet jokes are old hat, to the point of tediousness. True/false?

Comment: @Chris: I don't know, but Jon Skeet probably does.

Comment: @Bill good point. I will do some research about how widely those terms are used in JS world.

Comment: Why do we have a `[crockford]` tag but not a `[jon-skeet]` tag?

Comment: @zzzzBov And Douglas Crockford probably qualifies as an expert too.

Comment: @SztupY Because you haven't added the [`[jon-skeet]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jon-skeet) tag yet, obviously.

Comment: @Yakk It thought it was because tags went on *questions*, not *answers*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just finished burninating [crockford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crockford).

While burninating this tag, I also found [railroad-diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/railroad-diagram) which started off as a reference to the railroad diagram in one of his books, and evolved into a strange mix of completely unrelated questions. Some were about the specific diagram, others were about syntax diagrams, and there were even Ruby on Rails questions mixed in.

Answer (score -16):

And if we do nothing what happens? There is the answer.

Comment: Are you anti-tag-burnination?