# Following our standards: Burninate the [ansi] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

I suggest that the [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) tag be the next tag burninated. The tag excerpt says:

> American National Standards Institute (ANSI)

and the tag info wiki says

> "The Institute oversees the creation, promulgation and use of thousands of norms and guidelines that directly impact businesses in
>   nearly every sector: from acoustical devices to construction
>   equipment, from dairy and livestock production to energy distribution,
>   and many more. ANSI is also actively engaged in accrediting programs
>   that assess conformance to standards – including globally-recognized
>   cross-sector programs such as the ISO 9000 (quality) and ISO 14000
>   (environmental) management systems."

Quite a wide field of expertise.

It has 820 tagged questions, and, oddly enough, 28 followers.

There were primarily 5 groups of questions, which could be retagged as follows:

- [codepages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codepages) or [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) for "ANSI" codepages, which is a misnomer, since none of that stuff was ever standardized by ANSI; and these questions often concern codepages that never even *purported* to be standardized by ANSI.
- [ansi-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-escape) for terminal escape sequences based on ANSI X3.64,
- [c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89) for the ANSI X3.159-1989 / ISO/IEC 9899:1990 for C programming language,
- [ansi-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-sql) for the SQL standard,
- And possibly some [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) questions that would want to be [C++-98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863051/what-is-ansi-c) ([c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98)).

These 5 have nothing to do with each other, except by having been factually or imaginarily standardized by the American National Standards Institute at some point of their history; also the combination [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal) [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) could mean the question handles any or all of the first 3. And all of these 5 cases have perfectly valid tags already that more clearly describe the content; the existence of [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) just aids laziness.

Comment: There's also [ansi-term], [ansi-colors], [ansi-c], [ansi-nulls], [ansistring], [ansicon] and [ansi-sql-92] to consider (and perhaps other tags containing but not starting with `ansi`).  Some of those may be valid (ansi-term seems to be an emacs thing).

Comment: Yeah they are pretty much valid as such for example ansi-nulls is a sqlserver setting, ansicon seems to be some project, ansistring a type in Delphi (ill named as such as it refers to the item 1 on the list); except [ansi-c] with 4 questions ought to be a synonym for [c89], however I do not have any posts in [c89] and therefore no upvotes to suggest the synonym.

Comment: Ah actually, [ansi-sql-92] is also a misnomer, since sql-92 standardization was undertaken by ISO

Comment: @Jeff Anyway, only a mod can add a synonym from [ansi-c] to [c89]. Not sure it's that useful keeping it around even as a synonym, but whatever...

Comment: What about [iso], [w3c] and the like?

Comment: if [ansi] is well-received, they should follow along with [ecma] and [ieee]

Comment: This reminds me of the "soup nazi" that came up recently again.  A tag like [ansi] is used by a hapless C programmer that never learned how to deal with Unicode.  If he *knew* that the proper term was [character-encoding] then he'd never have asked the question.  Tags are for questioners, an expert already knows the proper term.  There's very little point in removing the few words the questioner knows to describe his issue.

Comment: @HansPassant at least we remove the words that *really* don't describe his issue, with the plus that that way the expert may find (and properly tag) the question.

Comment: It is better that the post is tagged with just [c] instead of [c] + lots of other tags that do not describe the post at all.

Comment: Much of the confusion with character encoding comes from Microsoft, who consistently uses the term "ANSI String" for any string that isn't Unicode. They even went so far as to add an "A" to many of their API functions that take such a string. I'm with @HansPassant that we need *something* for people confused by that - perhaps a new tag `ansi-string`?

Comment: In addition to that, people talk about ASCII vs ANSI, yet at least ASCII was standardized by ASA->USASI->ANSI, while the 'ANSI' wasn't.

Comment: @Mark - AnsiString is a class used in Borland's framework.  Free Pascal uses it too.  The [ansistring] tag already exists.

Answer (score 25):

Here are my answers to the questions in [When to burninate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/159034) for [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi)

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?**

The tag wiki is about the American National Standards Institute, which is an organization that does *a lot*. And the questions tagged are usually about different standards associated with ANSI, such as ANSI C ([c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89)/[ansi-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-c)), character encoding, and ANSI escape codes. So I would say it *kind of describes the questions*, in the same [way that [crockford] describes JavaScript questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253760/359284).

**Is it unambiguous?**

The [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) tag isn't ambiguous, the questions within it *somehow relate* to specifications or standards that ANSI played a role in.

But *it is broad*. ANSI was involved in a lot of standard, including (but definitely not limited to) C 89 (ANSI C), escape codes (often used in terminals), and ANSI SQL. The tag only helps to inform future users that ANSI was *involved in some way* with one of the technologies involved, and there are far better tags that make it more specific.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yeah, totally. Most, if not all, of the questions are programming related.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Only when used in combination with other tags, like [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding). But even then we have tags that better describe it, like [c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89), [ansi-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-sql) and [ansi-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-escape).

---

So with that, I think it should be burninated. Here is a list of my proposed retags

- [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) -> [c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89) [(297 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+c)

  - [ansi-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-c) should also be made a synonym of [c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89)
- <del>[ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors) -> [ansi-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-escape) [(25 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+colors)</del>

  - <del>[ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escaping) -> [ansi-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-escape) [(16 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+escaping)</del>
  - <del>[ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal) -> [ansi-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-escape) [(25 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+terminal)</del>
  - [ansi-colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-colors) should also be made a synonym of [ansi-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-escape)
- Various encoding questions should be re-tagged [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) (and sometimes also [ansistring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansistring))

  - [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding) -> [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) [(49 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+encoding)
  - [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utf-8) -> [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) [(83 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+utf-8)
  - [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unicode) -> [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) [(66 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+unicode)
  - <del>[ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ascii) -> [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) [(16 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+ascii)</del>
- <del>[ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi) + [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) -> [ansi-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-sql) [(61 questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+sql)</del>

And then we are left with [just under 200 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi+-c+-escaping+-colors+-sql+-unicode+-encoding+-utf-8+-ascii+-terminal) to handle it.

*(If there are others that I missed, feel free to edit this)*

Comment: I don't think you're interpretation of "unambiguous" works here. A tag that applies to everything that is ANSI isn't unambiguous, it just has a large coverage that can apply to multiple things. In contrast, `tls` has sometimes been used for "*thread local storage*": "tls" is ambiguous in that context (although I still think we should keep `tls`, since the confusion is really rare). Tags are meant to identify a set, there's nothing wrong with querying the intersection of two sets (e.g. `ansi` + `sql`).

Comment: If you remove every mention of "ansi" from the character-encoding questions, it's going to be harder to Google them. Remember that Microsoft calls those ANSI strings, so that's what people will search for.

Comment: @MarkRansom With any luck, questions tagged with [tag:ansi] mention ANSI somewhere in the question, so I can't see that being a huge issue. Though I do see the "ANSI strings" possibly being an issue, though I have no idea what the solution would be.

Comment: Just retag to include [ansistring], and there's not even a potential problem.

Comment: @Deduplicator [tag:ansistring] should probably get a tag wiki then.

Comment: Maybe even better (or in addition): [tag:codepage]...